# Breaks in Brahmacharya

Tags: scripture, brahmacharya

Could anyone point me towards any scriptural reference that explain the breaks to a celibacy vow?

I have read of Swami Sivananda explain the below as breaks to Brahmacharya:

Darshan – looking at a member of the opposite sex with carnal desire.
Sparsha – desire to touch, embrace or be near a person of the opposite sex.
Keertan – praising his or her qualities to your friends.
Keli – amorous sport with the opposite sex.
Guhya Bhaashan – talking privately to a member of the opposite sex.
Sankalpa – lustful thought of the opposite sex.
Adhyavasaaya – strong desire for carnal knowledge.
Kriya Nivritti – sexual enjoyment.

I was wondering if these have their source in any tantric/yogic scriptures.
I also want to know if merely being in the presence of women is considered a break in celibacy according to any shastras. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

> Darshan – looking at a member of the opposite sex with carnal desire.
>   Sparsha – desire to touch, embrace or be near a person of the opposite
>   sex. Keertan – praising his or her qualities to your friends. Keli –
>   amorous sport with the opposite sex. Guhya Bhaashan – talking
>   privately to a member of the opposite sex. Sankalpa – lustful thought
>   of the opposite sex. Adhyavasaaya – strong desire for carnal
>   knowledge. Kriya Nivritti – sexual enjoyment.

The source of these assertions, which you are looking for, is the scripture called **Daksha Smriti** which gives us the concept of *Ashtavidha Maithuna* - the eight kinds of sexual congress. Here are the verses:

> [A Yogin} should always preserve his Brahmacharyya [celibacy];
>   **Sexual intercourse is of eight sorts** : -viz: thinking of a woman, talking [about it] -dalliance with a woman, looking [at a woman with
>   an impure desire] speaking to her secretly, determination [for holding
>   a sexual congress], persistent endeavour [for doing it] and the actual
>   deed. The learned hold that these are the eight divisions of sexual
>   intercourse.
>
> **Daksha Smriti 7-32,33**

So, one is said to violate the vow of Brahmacharya if one indulges in any one of the eight kinds of sexual activities.

Comment: These are things that constitute sexual intercourse, not what breaks the vow of Brahmacharya. Wouldn't only intentional emission of semen constitute transgression of the vow as the Manumsmriti says?

Comment: Those are all types of sexual congresses. The last one among them is "actually doing it" and all the others equivalent  so indulging in any one of them will break the vow. @Ikshvaku

Comment: Oh ok. Can you link an English copy of the Daksha Smriti?

Comment: As I hv said earlier, I hv to search.. I downloaded a copy years back which hv this and other Smritis. @Ikshvaku

Answer (score 2):

Brahmanas, Kshatriya, and Vaishyas all undergo Upanayanam as early as 7 years of age. Having done Upanayanam, they become Brahmacharis.

One important vow of Brahmacharya is maintenance of celibacy, meaning no intentional emission of semen (masturbation or sex).

Here is what the *Manusmriti* says:

> Persons learned in the Veda and knowing the law declare that for the
> twice-born person keeping up his vows, **the intentional emission of
> semen means a ‘transgression of the vow.’**—(120)

This vow is very important to be maintained, as stated in the next verse:

> The spiritual power of the Religious Student (Brahmachari), who has
> become ‘immoral,’ (Avakirnin) ‘goes away into the Maruts, Indra,
> Bṛhaspati and Agni.—(121)

In fact, that's the reason given in the Apastamba sutras as to why no Rishis are born in kali yuga:

> The word 'austerity' (must be understood to apply) to (the observance
> of) the rules (of studentship).
>
> If they are transgressed, study drives out the knowledge of the Veda
> acquired already, from the (offender) and from his children.
>
> Besides he will go to hell, and his life will be shortened.
>
> **On account of that (transgression of the rules of studentship) no
> Rishis are born amongst the men of later ages [Kali yuga].**

So, only an intentional emission of semen constitutes a break in the vow of Brahmacharya.

However, the *Apastamba Dharma Sutras* say this:

> strībhir yāvad artha saṃbhāṣī || 16 ||
>
> 16. Let him talk with women as much [only] as is necessary.

So, I would say that if you have sexual relations or interaction with a woman, but don't intentionally emit your semen, then you broke the rules of Brahmacharya, although you didn't technically violate the vow of Brahmacharya.